# IF statement to check url in PHP with RegEx

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I would like to change the language of my content on my search results template.  Since the Spanish versions of each page are in a sub-directory `/es/` I have been able to successfully manage content with Javascript using some simple RegEx.  However, this template is in a `.php` file. How can I check to see if the page is in the `/es/` sub-directory?

Here is my initial thinking (obvious syntax issue, just tried to get structure going):

```
<?php
    $spanishPage = "/.*\/es\//"; 
     if (preg_match($spanishPage, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { ?>
        <h2>Spanish results for: <span><?php the_search_query(); ?></span></h2>
     <?php
     }
     else { ?>
        <h2>English results for: <span><?php the_search_query(); ?></span></h2>
    <?php
    } ?>
```

Using strpos:

```
<?php 
                            $spanishPage = "/.*\/es\//"; 
                            if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $spanishPage)) {
                                echo 'This is spanish page';
                            }
                            else {
                                echo 'this is an english page';
                            }
                        ?>
```

Comment: Remove `g` flag, PHP regexps do not support this flag.

Comment: @wiktor - ok I have removed that, does it look correct now?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation on `strpos` and `preg_match` for expected arguments, and then pick one or the other to use.

Comment: @miken32 this is where I am stuck, I am thinking `preg_match` is closer to what I need and I have updated my code above, any help would be great

Comment: This is a simple substring search; things do not get more basic. At a glance, what you have should work. `strpos` would be perfectly adequate for such a simple search though.

Comment: @miken32 since this seems like something that is easy for you, can you please provide an answer? I tried the `strpos` method and added that to my question above, but still not working to identify a Spanish page

Comment: `strpos` takes a string as a parameter, not a regular expression. As I said, your code using `preg_match` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in `$spanishPage` are for regular expressions, strpos doesn't use them

```
<?php

// a regular expression that will get a language code out of a URL 
$regEx = '#/(\w\w)/(.*)$#';

// use the regex with the request URL
if(preg_match_all($regEx,'https://www.example.com/es/my-page.php',$matches)) {
        if (is_dir($matches[1][0])) {
                echo 'Directory is '.$matches[1][0].PHP_EOL;
                echo 'Page is '.$matches[2][0];
                if (!is_file($matches[2][0])) {
                        echo ' not found';
                }
        } else {
                echo 'Directory '.$matches[1][0].' doesn\'t exist'.PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```